# How to send an attachment from an upload button using nodemailer

Tags: html, forms, handlebars.js, nodemailer

I am trying to create a website with a form that users can fill up as well as uploading an image or a docx file through the input tag. I am using a controller because I am also using an hbs for this.

```
const output = `<p>You have a new message from the TIPH website<p>
    <h3>Contact Details</h3>
    <p>Name: ${req.body.contact_name}<p>
    <h3>Inquiry</h3>
    <p>${req.body.contact_inquiry}</p>
    `;
    
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAIL,
          pass: process.env.PASSWORD
        }
      });
      
      var mailOptions = {
        from: `${req.body.contact_email}`,
        to: '...',
        subject: `${req.body.contact_subject}`,
        html: output,
        attachments: [
            {
                filename: `${req.body.contact_upload}`,
            }
        ]
      };
      
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
          res.render('contact-us', {
            layout: '/layouts/main',
            title: 'Contact Us',
            contact_active: true,
            msg: 'Your message has been sent!'
        })
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to upload files to a node server, you should set the `enctype` attribute of the HTML form element to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

To work with the files server side you could use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). This middleware makes the uploaded file availabe from the `req.file` property.

You can then add this file to the `attachments` array. You can find what props you need to send to Nodemailer in their [documentation](https://nodemailer.com/message/).